# How to add break lines for output, based on input?

Tags: python

**Question**

How can I write code which will insert insert break lines in the output, *where there was one in the input?*

**Code**

```
data1=[]
with open("FileInput1.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        data1.append([float(f) for f in line.strip().split()])


data2=[]
with open("FileInput2.csv") as File2:
    for line in File2:
        data2.append([f for f in line.strip().split()])
```

**Sample Input:**

1. File Input # 1

   ```
   1223 32  (userID - int = 1223, work hours = 32)
   2004 12.2  
   8955 80
   ```

   a. Current Output

   ```
   1223 32 2004 12.2 8955 80
   ```
2. FileInput2:

   ```
   UserName  3423 23.6  
   Name      6743 45.9
   ```

   a. Current Output

   ```
   UserName 3423 23.6 Name 6743 45.9
   ```

Comment: Mind supplying a sample fileDoc.txt? on [pastebin](http://http://pastebin.com/) and I'll mock something up in the next 5 minutes.

Comment: Please consider using the built-in `csv` module. There are lots of related SO questions and answers.

Comment: @Killrawr i just added two different files that i will be reading from

Comment: what do you mean by allow a break line? you mean the original file does not have break lines?

Comment: what is wrong with your current code? how does i differ from your expected output?

Comment: @jurgenreza  all my output result are on one line and i want to return results each line by line

Comment: so your reading is correct. post the code you use for writing. where are you writing the output? are you printing it? or writing it to another file?

Comment: @jurgenreza - no i am just printing on the screen

Comment: What do you want the input to actually look like...?

Comment: for i in data1: print(i)

Comment: @xxmbabanexx i want the output to look like the input each line read in will be printed again on a single line - currently it is printing all the info in the file on a single line

Comment: So... this is a programming exercise in which the output is *exactly* the same as the input?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx lol after asking a 100 questions I think you are right.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx - lol yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preclude**

Based on the cryptic messages of the God's (*please* don't be offended) I have deciphered [Amina's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15374387/1993598) question. This was the conversation that led to it all:

```
So... this is a programming exercise in which the output is exactly
the same as the input? 
– xxmbabanexx 12 mins ago 


@xxmbabanexx - lol yes – Amina 8 mins ago
```

**Answer**

To keep the newlines in your output, you need to simply print the *exact* file out. If I hadn't had the above conversation, I would have given a more complex answer. Here is the answer, given step-by-step.

```
"""
Task: Make a program which returns the exact same output as the input
Ideas:
print the output!!
"""
```

^This helps me to understand the quesiton

```
first_input = "Input_One.txt"
second_input = "Input_Two.txt"



Input_One = open(first_input, "r")
Input_Two = open (first_input, "r")


Output_One = open("Output_One.txt", "w")
Output_Two = open ("Output_Two.txt", "w")
```

^I create and open my two files.

```
x = Input_One.read()
y = Input_Two.read()
```

^I read the info, assigning it the the variables `x` and `y`

```
print "OUTPUT 1:\n", x
print "\n"
print "OUTPUT 2:\n", y
```

^I show the output to the user

```
#Save "output"

Output_One.write(x)
Output_Two.write(y)

print"\nCOMPLETE!"
```

^I save the output and give a message.

Comment: This should work for as many input text files as you have. I did not try to use it for .csv files.

Comment: You made me laugh :D I will go ahead and give it a try even though i was looking for a simple fix with what i had. Could i have "\n" at the end of the append line.

Comment: @Amina What do I need to do to get the "magical" check. And yes, I am an *expert* (not) in geek humor.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is just merging several lines in your file into a single line.

```
def printer(filename, data):
  with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(data.replace("\n", "  "))


for filename in ["FileInput1.txt", "FileInput2.csv"]:
  with open(filename) as f:
    printer("new" + filename, f.read())
```